# Standard deviation (/error) of error function erf(x)

Tags: dataset

When fitting peaks in measured data I usually fit a gaussian and use the standard deviation as an error. The position is at $13.2 \pm 3.4$ for example.

Now we want to fit a sigmoid as we have a smeared plateau. We usually use $\tanh(x)$ or $\operatorname{erf}(x)$. So I fitted $a\cdot\operatorname{scipy.special.erf}(b(x-x_0))+c$ to my data, which works perfectly. How do I get a reasonable guess for my error from the parameters $a$, $b$, or $c$?

The question is not python specific, it's rather maths/physics related.

Thank you very much

Comment: The uncertainty in the position of a peak is *not* the standard deviation of the Gaussian.

Comment: Rob Jeffries is totally right. The estimated error for the parameters of your fit depends on the fit method. What method are you using? Least squares? Maximum likelihood? Something else?

Comment: 1. How is this a physics question rather than a statistics question (which should go to [stats.SE])? 2. Any reasonable fitting procedure will deliver error on the fit parameters, if yours doesn't, this is purely related to your specific fitting procedure.

Comment: When the computed quantities are the result of complex computations, the best method is to use [resampling methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no physics content and belongs on another site such as Cross Validated SE.